# sendAndConfirmTransaction does not exist for typ connection

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, typescript

How can I solve this? as far as I have seen, it has the typ connection..

````
export async function createMint(
  wallet: WalletAdapter,
  mintAuthority: Keypair,
  decimals: number
) {
  if (!wallet.connected) {
    throw new Error('Wallet is not connected');
  }

  const mint = Keypair.generate();
  const instructions: TransactionInstruction[] = [];

  instructions.push(
    TokenInstructions.initializeMint({
      mint: mint.publicKey,
      decimals: decimals,
      mintAuthority: mintAuthority.publicKey,
    })
  );
  if (!mintAuthority.secretKey || mintAuthority.secretKey.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('mintAuthority does not contain a private key');
  }

  const connection = new Connection('https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=5d69c879-36f4-4acf-87b4-e44a64c07acc');
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(...instructions);
  transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
  transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;

  // Sign the transaction with the payer
  transaction.sign(mintAuthority);
    
  // Serialize and send the transaction
  try{
    const signature = await connection.sendAndConfirmTransaction(transaction,[mintAuthority]);  // sendAndConfirmTransaction does not exist for typ connection
    return {
      mint,
      transaction: signature,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Transaction error', error);
    throw error;
  }
}  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

`sendAndConfirmTransaction` is a helper function in the web3.js library, and you can see its implementation at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/5b21c65e6779dd873d0a2d5ba2c7dd1ca607e2be/packages/library-legacy/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts#L18

Be sure to import it properly using something like:

```
import { sendAndConfirmTransaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
```